# cuda: how to copy host data to 3D cuda array and back

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, cuda

The "cuda c programming guide" gives examples on using cuda arrays.
Those examples are limited to 2D. So in case of a 2D cuda array I would simply do the following
to copy host data to device memory:

```
// Copy to device memory some data located at address h_data in host memory  
// cuInputArray is a 2D cuda array
cudaMemcpyToArray(cuInputArray, 0, 0, host_data, size_bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
// with e.g. size_bytes := size_arr_x * size_arr_y * sizeof(float)
```

I tried the same approach with cuInputArray being a 3D cuda array without much success,
getting invalid argument errors.

So how would get my host data to device memory AND back?

Comment: Do you want copy it to the global memory? or the texture memory?

Comment: @pQB: there isn't any such thing as copy to texture memory in CUDA.

Comment: @talonmies (always on the lookout :) You are right. What I mean is if he wanted to read the input data from global memory or from texture memory.

Comment: global memory would suffice for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to copy 3D data into the GPU device memory, you need to do the following:

1. **Allocate** the memory space with **`cudaMalloc3D`**
2. **Setup** the input parameters with **`cudaMemcpy3DParms`**
3. **Copy** input data from host to device with **`cudaMemcpy3D`**

Then, to get your data back to the host:

1. **Setup** the output parameters with **`cudaMemcpy3DParms`**
2. **Copy** output data from device to host with **`cudaMemcpy3D`**

The Chapter 3.2.2 Device Memory of the CUDA C Programming Guide has a *code sample that allocates a width×height×depth 3D array of floating-point values and shows how to loop over the array elements in device code*.

Also the `simpleTexture3D` example of the CUDA SDK is a good starting point.

Just a **recommendation**: Prepare your code to catch CUDA error and analyse what is happening in case of error because you would probably find a few.

Comment: I preferred to describe the steps as your question is not about programming, but knowledge of CUDA.

Comment: I think that points me into the right direction.
Appreciate it!
I assume in my case 1. would be cudaMalloc3DArray?

Comment: CUDA arrays are opaque memory layouts optimized for texture fetching (CUDA C Programming Guide, chapter 3.2.10.3), so if you want read data from global memory you should use `cudaMalloc3D`.